# Filter multiple items based on array of values

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box that is populated using ng-options.

```
$scope.items = [
   {ID: '2012', Title: 'Chicago'},
   {ID: '2013', Title: 'New York'},
   {ID: '2014', Title: 'Washington'},
];

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items | filter:filterItemNames">
</select>
```

This returns...

```
<option value="2012">Chicago</option>
<option value="2013">New York</option>
<option value="2014">Washington</option>
```

I would like to filter and display *multiple* items based on their name (i.e. New York and Chicago).

I'm currently trying to use an array with item names to filter, but this is not working.

```
$scope.filterItemNames = ['New York', 'Chicago'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could create custom filter function:

```
$scope.filterByNames = function(el) {
    return !$scope.filterItemNames || $scope.filterItemNames.indexOf(el.Title) > -1;
};
```

and use it like this in HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
        ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items | filter:filterByNames">
</select>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/lqiMIlEYdrLlS6K0H2g9?p=preview

Comment: This works but only if filterItemNames is not null or empty. Is there an option to exclude filtering?